# How to create figures with strongly connected components

Tags: graphs

I would like to create the following figure in latex.
Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Best

**EDIT**

What I tried so far:

I tried the code below however, I could not be able to sketch the circles around.
Also, could not add letters inside a circle.

```
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix{ 
   A  &           & B \ar[ll] \ar[d] & C \ar[l] \ar[d]  \\
      & D \ar[ur] & E \ar[u]         & F \ar[l] \ar[u]  \\
      &           & G \ar[dl] \ar[u] & H \ar[l] \ar[u]  \\ 
      & I \ar[r]  & J \ar[u] \ar[d]  & K \ar[u]         \\
      &           & L \ar[ur]        &           
} 
\end{displaymath}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Here my workflow for the first picture. I would work with `tikz` and personally prefer using `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` for this kind of approach. Define the positions for your nodes, draw some circles and, at the and, the arrows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    
    \tikzset{%
        every node/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=0.5cm},
    }
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        %nodes
        
        \node(A) at (0,0) {A};
        \node(B)[anchor=west] at ($(A.east) + (2,0)$) {B};
        \node(C)[anchor=west] at ($(B.east) + (2,0)$) {C};
        \node(E)[anchor=north] at ($(B.south) + (0,-1)$) {E};
        \node(F) at (E-|C) {F};
        \node(D)[anchor=east] at ($(E.west) + (-1,0)$) {D};
        \node(G)[anchor=north] at ($(E.south) + (0,-3)$) {G};
        \node(H) at (G-|F) {H};
        \node(J)[anchor=north] at ($(G.south) + (0.5,-1)$) {J};
        \node(K)[anchor=north] at ($(H.south) + (0.5,-1)$) {K};
        \node(I)[anchor=east] at ($(J.west) + (-1,0)$) {I};
        \node(L)[anchor=north] at ($(J.south) + (1,-1)$) {L};
        
        %grouping circles
        
        \draw[densely dashed] (A) circle[radius=0.75cm];
        \draw[densely dashed] (D) circle[radius=0.75cm];
        \draw[densely dashed] ($(B)!0.5!(E)$) circle [x radius=0.75cm, y radius=1.5cm];
        \draw[densely dashed] ($(C)!0.5!(F)$) circle [x radius=0.75cm, y radius=1.5cm];
        \draw[densely dashed] ($(I)!0.5!(K)$) circle [radius=3cm];
        
        %arrows
        
        \draw[-latex] (B) edge (A);
        \draw[-latex] (D) edge (B);
        \draw[-latex] (C) edge (B);
        \draw[-latex] (E) edge[bend right] (B);
        \draw[-latex] (B) edge[bend right] (E);
        \draw[-latex] (F) edge[bend right] (C);
        \draw[-latex] (C) edge[bend right] (F);     
        \draw[-latex] (F) edge (E);
        \draw[-latex] (G) edge (E);
        \draw[-latex] (H) edge (F);
        \draw[-latex] (H) edge (G);
        \draw[-latex] (G) edge (I);
        \draw[-latex] (I) edge (J);
        \draw[-latex] (J) edge (G);
        \draw[-latex] (J) edge (L);
        \draw[-latex] (L) edge (K);
        \draw[-latex] (K) edge (H);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now you can have a try for the right picture. In case you need some help, let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much Excelsior. I can now get the whole figure. Best.